# What is a good place in Las Vegas for a scotch and cigar?

Tags: alcohol, nightlife, las-vegas, smoking

I'm going to be in Las Vegas for a couple days for a conference and would like to take some time to break away one evening for a scotch and a cigar, what would be a good place to head towards where I could do both? Ideally the establishment would be a bit quieter as I would like a chance to relax.

Comment: This might need an additional tag such as `cigar-bar` or the like but I don't seem to have the reputation yet to do so.

Comment: Actually we try to avoid tags in the singular and unless we expect many questions on a topic and that topic is sufficiently differentiated from other topics, we don't usually give it its own tag. We thought about this in meta and decided `nightlife` was the closest we had for cigar bars.

Comment: @hippietrail - Understandable, they do tend to be a bit niche in general.

Answer (score 5):

Some of these might be out of date, but the asylum.com has [this list of top ten cigar bars in Las Vegas](http://www.asylum.com/2010/03/11/top-10-las-vegas-cigar-bars-sin-citys-smokiest-joints/) from 2010:

- Carmine's Little Italy Sport & Cigar Lounge
- Havana Club Cigar Lounge
- Andre's Monte Carlo
- Casa Fuente
- Fontana Bar
- Rhumbar
- Nine Fine Irishmen
- Baccarat Bar
- VooDoo Steak & Lounge
- Dino's Lounge